# Binary data displayed instead of image in c# and mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString.ToString());
            // Create SQL Command 
            int adid= int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["adid"]);
            int imgid = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["imgid"]);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            //cmd.CommandText = "Select i.image_id, i.image_name, i.image_byteImage, i.image_adId from images i,postadverties p where i.image_adId =@ID";
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT image_id,image_byteImage FROM images WHERE image_adId="+ adid + " and image_id="+ imgid;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            //MySqlParameter AdId = new MySqlParameter("@ID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
            //MySqlParameter imgid = new MySqlParameter("@imgid", MySqlDbType.Int32);
            //AdId.Value = 
            //imgid.Value = 
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(AdId);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(imgid);
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dReader.Read())
            {
                byte[] binaryimg = (byte[])dReader["image_byteImage"];
                string base64string = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(binaryimg);
                context.Response.Write(base64string);
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.End();
            }
            dReader.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
```

[Click here to see result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XhrI.png)
When trying to display images stored in database above result is displayed instead of image.No clue why this issue is coming.Is there any problem while converting it or some else.In another page it works and on some pages it does not.